# Issue on adding home screen shortcut on ZTE Overture 2 running Lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, home-screen-shortcuts

I have ZTE Overture 2 running Lollipop and I can't figure out how to do this at all. In my Android 4.0.x phone, I would simply go to the Apps button/icon, press and hold any app's icon, and drag it to any of the home screens. Now, when I do that in Android Lollipop, the icon stays in the home screen and there is a bar to the top with a trash can icon to the left and the word Uninstall to the right. I can't figure out how to cancel this act, so I am forced to restart my phone and I am left still not knowing how to add a shortcut to an app to the home screen.

I moved some programs to the SD card and now that I restarted my phone, they are no longer on the home screen and one folder in which I had some icons, is gone entirely.

Comment: It is the same way as before, it only uninstalls if you bring the icon to the uninstall section.

Comment: Wow. This new phone is making me look like a fool. The uninstall bar was staying there and the icon would be like frozen wherever I put it. When I switched to different home screens the icon would stay in the same spot but all the other icons would go away to show me the other home screen I selected.

Comment: I restarted the phone a few times trying to increase my chances of getting a successful bluetooth pairing and I guess that did the trick with this also. Thanks @TristanWiley for your help. It worries me a bit that a new phone is acting up like this though.

Comment: Hmm it could be a bug.  You said it's new, where did you get it? Also, what phone is it? Do you have a warranty?

Comment: I'll just hope it's a one time thing for now. It's the ZTE Overture 2 that I got from one of Cricket Wireless' stores.

Comment: You can try bringing it back, this definitely shouldn't be happening.  You could also try resetting the phone if there's an option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25055/discussion-between-rolo-and-tristan-wiley).

Answer (score 1):

> How to add a shortcut for any app to the home screen in Android Lollipop?

I'm aware of two app based methods that can do the job on Lollipop 5.0 and are listed below:

## Method #1

Install and launch [QuickShortcutMaker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sika524.android.quickshortcut) → under **Applications** choose the app whose shortcut you want at your Home screen → select **Create**.

The app shortcut is now placed at Home screen. During the shortcut creation you can change the icon or name of the shortcut too.

**Note** that if your Launcher isn't showing the shortcut using the aforesaid instructions then go to **Widgets** section of your Launcher and add **QuickShortcutMaker** widget to get the job done.

## Method #2

If Method #1 didn't work, or you've [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) installed then you may use it for the objective.

<sub>Pressing Back Key saves the changes in Tasker app.</sub>

1. Go to **Widgets** section in your Launcher and choose **Task Shortcut**
2. Select **New Task** → name it (name of the app shortcut) and select **OK**
3. Tap `+` → **App** → **Launch App** → choose the app for the shortcut → tap Back key
4. In the **Task Shortcut** window tap [image: 3x3 square icon] → **Application icon** → choose the icon you want on the shortcut → tap Back key to come back to Home screen.

Your shortcut is now placed at Home Screen and is ready for launch.

Answer (score 0):

I use the paid version of Nova Launcher ([Nova Prime](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher.prime)) as my default home screen. It allows to set shortcuts to any activity by long-pressing anywhere on the home screen as well as placing any icon of your choice